# Counterexample to an implication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Denote $\bar{A}$ a complement of $A$ in a set $\Omega$ and $A \Delta B = A/B \cup B/A$ the symmetric difference of $A, B$. It is claimed that for a map $\phi := \Omega \rightarrow \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace, \; \phi(\emptyset) = 0$:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\phi(A) & \phi(\bar{A}) \\
\hline
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}, \, A \in \Omega  \implies \phi(A \Delta B) = \phi(A) + \phi(B),  \text{  and } \phi(\Omega) = 1
$$

I know of a counterexample to this. Let $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ be a set of all subsets (a power set) of set $\alpha$. Consider $\phi: \Omega \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, $\Omega = \mathcal{P}({\lbrace a, b, c \rbrace})$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\phi(a) &= 0 &
\phi(b) &= 1 &
\phi(c) &= 1 & 
\phi(\emptyset) &= 0 \\
\phi(b \cup c ) &= 1 &
\phi(a \cup c) &= 0 &
\phi(a \cup b) &= 0 &
\phi(a \cup b \cup c) &= 1
\end{align*}
$$

which satisfies the truth table, but breaks linearity ($\phi(a \Delta c) = \phi(a \cup b) = 0 \neq \phi(a) + \phi(c) = 1$).

I am interested if the following could be also implied by the LHS and also lead to a valid counter:

$$
\phi(A \Delta B) = \phi(A) + \phi(B) + \phi(A)\phi(B), \, \text{ and } \phi(\Omega)  =1
$$

Choosing $\phi(A) = 0$ implies that:
$$
\phi(A \Delta \bar{A}) = \phi(\Omega) = 1 = \phi(A) + \phi(\bar{A})(1 + \phi(A)) = \phi(\bar{A})$$
and hence: $\phi(A) = 0 \implies\phi(\bar{A}) = 1$ and $\phi(\bar{A}) = 0 \implies \phi(A) = 1$.

Choosing $\phi(A) = 1$ however leads to:
$$
1 = 1 + \phi(\bar{A})\cdot 0 = 1
$$
no matter what $\phi(\bar{A})$ is, so the opposite implication is not simply shown to hold. Is there any way out of this to finish the counter?

Note: If you can think of a better title for the question, please let me know.

Comment: The domain of $\phi$ is $\Omega$ or $\cal P(\Omega)$? The sum is union?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Thanks a lot, edited. Please let me know if it makes more sense now.

Comment: Given the table in the box of the post, it seems clear that $\phi$ should be a map defined on the collection of all subsets of $\Omega,$ which also happens to satisfy that it maps into $\{0,1\}$ and (by the table) satisfies $\phi(A')=1-\phi(A)$ [where $A'$ here is complement]. Please confirm whether this is what you mean.

Comment: @coffeemath: Correct. Do you think it would help to define $\phi: 2^\Omega \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ (ie. map from power set of $\Omega$ to $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$?) to remove this ambiguity?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Thanks for the suggestion to change the domain to powerset- edited.

Comment: A simpler counterexample to the original assertion: $\Omega=\wp(\{a\}$, $\varphi(\varnothing)=1$. Then $\varphi(\varnothing+\{a\})=\varphi(\{a\})=0$, but $\varphi(\varnothing)+\varphi(\{a\})=1+0=1$. This probem will always arise when $\varphi(\varnothing)=1$, since $\varnothing$ is the identity for symmetric difference.

Comment: vojta-- In your definition of $\phi$ it may be better notation to give the domain elements as sets, not sums, e.g. $\phi(\{a,c\})=0,$ etc. The notation you use of $a+b$ makes it seem there is additive structure somewhere.

Comment: @coffeemath - Ok, I will restate the problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for pointing that out! The original statement of the proof forces $\phi(\emptyset) = 0 $ - edited.